# modify the default login in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

i need to modify the default login, (email and password).
I must use a field other than email to make the login

User Model:

```
  protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    't_matricula',
    'matricula',
    'number',
    'password',
];
```

i could use the Number field as data to login, **where should I modify to use Number instead of Name?**

Comment: Your question contradicts itself. You say email and password, but then ask where to use number instead of name. You're also not using both Laravel 5 and Laravel 8, so which is it?

Comment: Like Brian said, please explain your situation clearly. I edited your answer according to the points they made, but please edit it further to get the answers you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say that the field you want to use is `number` instead of `email` all you have to do is to go to the `LoginController` in the following path `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`
and add the following method:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'number';
}
```

by the way the field **must be a string**.